# flutter: Class '_ImmutableMap<String, Object>' has no instance getter 'options'. Receiver: Instance of '_ImmutableMap<String, Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to load the list question in question.dart into main.dart.
I wrote the code as

```
final newoptions = quiz[1].options
```

to get the options('good') in the second of the list question.

But after running it I get this error:

> Class '_ImmutableMap<String, Object>' has no instance getter
> 'options'. Receiver: Instance of '_ImmutableMap<String, Object>' Tried
> calling: options

How do I solve this?

question.dart

```
class Question {
  final int id;
  final String options;


  Question({required this.id, required this.options});
}

const List quiz = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "options": 'hello',
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "options": 'good',
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "options": 'abc',
  },
];
```

main.dart

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Body createState() => _Body();
}

class _Body extends State<Body> {
  final newoptions = quiz[1].options;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Try it this way `final newoptions = quiz[1]['options']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const List quiz = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "options": 'hello',
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "options": 'good',
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "options": 'abc',
  },
```

The above code is not a list of the class Question, it is a list of maps, if you want the list to be a list of Questions, it would look like this:

```
const List quiz = [
  Question(
    id: 1,
    options: 'hello',
  ),
  Question(
    id: 2,
    options: 'good',
  ),
  Question(
    id: 3,
    options: 'abc',
  ),
```

You can either change the list to what I just showed you, or change this line:

```
final newoptions = quiz[1].options
```

to this in order to access the map's values:

```
final newoptions = quiz[1]['options'];
```

If you do decide to not change the list into instances of `Question`, then you can get rid of the `Question` class, because you don't use it.